# How to execute Custom Script Execution in Azure runbook multiple times?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

actually, I´m trying to create a Azure runbook with a Custom Script Execution. The runbook run against a Linux VM.
I build a simple script which create a directory on the VM. If I execute the runbook the first time, then the directory will be created instantely. Then, I delete the directory, run the runbook again and the directory is not created again.
After some researching on the internet, I found a hint, that you can only run a script with the same parameters on a virtual machine once. So I added a timestamp in my SettingString.
Unfortunately, either this doesn´t solve the problem or I have an error in my code.

Hopefully you can help me out to find my error or give me an hint, how it is possible to execute a script multiple times against the same VM.

Thanks a lot!

```
$timestamp = (Get-Date).Ticks

Write-Output $timestamp

$SettingsString = '{"timestamp": "$timestamp", "fileUris":["myURI"],"commandToExecute":"sh myscript.sh"}';

$ProtectedSettingsString = '{"storageAccountName": "xxx","storageAccountKey":"xxx"}' 

Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -Location "xxx" -VMName "xxx" -Name "xxx" -Publisher "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions" -ExtensionType "CustomScriptForLinux" -TypeHandlerVersion 1.5 -SettingString $SettingsString -ProtectedSettingString $ProtectedSettingsString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Set-AzVMExtension` with `-ForceRerun` parameter to achieve this, you need to pass in a different string each time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmextension?view=azps-1.3.0

Comment: Thank you very much!! This was the solution and it is working now.